# How to scroll a Form to a specific UI element in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-form

I have a form on a SwiftUI NavigationView.
The form has no special elements, only the standard ones: TextField, DatePicker, and some Buttons

I would like to scroll programmatically to a specific element.
How can I achieve this?

ScrollViewReader does not seem to work with forms.

```
ScrollViewReader { p in
  Form {
    ....
    Button(action: {
      p.scrollTo(150)
    }) {
      Text(self.label)
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you prepare minimal reproducible example? It works, there might be some nuance in your code. The `id` must be present, unique, and match to what you scroll to.

Comment: exaclty, the id was missing, i thought scroll to is a position

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Give id to every element and pass this id to the `.scrollTo(id)` method.
Like this

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        ScrollViewReader { p in
            Form {
                Button(action: {
                }) {
                    Text("Top")
                }.id(150)
                
                ForEach(0..<30) { index in
                    Text("\(index)")
                        .id(index)
                }
                Button(action: {
                    p.scrollTo(150)
                }) {
                    Text("Scroll")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i think the ScrollViewReader needs to be inside the form, but then all elements behave as if they are not in form

Comment: I tested with Xcode 12.1 iOS 14.1. what issues are you facing exactly?

Comment: yes it works, sorry, i put the id on the wrong element

Comment: This is a great answer because I didn't realise Forms could be treated as scroll areas, and using this approach really improves the user experience for Form filling.